# Magento 2 : How to override place order button during payment on cash on delivery

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

please help me how to override the default place order button functionality in Magento during cash on delivery selection

Comment: why you want to overide?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to override the default place order Button so you need to mixin below file in your extenion

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js
```

**Your_vendorname/Your_extension_name/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default': {
            'Your_ExtrenionsName/js/view/payment/default-mixin': true
        }
    }
}};
```

**Your_vendorname/Your_extension_name/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default-mixin.js**

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko'
], function($, ko) {
'use strict';
var mixin = {
    initialize: function() {
        this._super();
    },
    placeOrder: function (data, event) {
        // You set action on place order button 
    }
};
return function(target) {
    return target.extend(mixin);
}});
```